# Modify URL in markdown link

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, markdown

I'm trying to modify a markdown file. In a file, there are many links like this one.

```
[string one](/stringtwo/#stringthree)
```

I'd like to change these to the following:

```
[string one](stringtwo.html#stringthree)
```

Remove slashes and add `.html`.

I tried the following:

```
sed -i 's/](\(\/.*\)#/](\1.html#/g' file
```

But it returns `[global configuration](/config/.html#globals)`. It doesn't remove slashes.

How can I achieve this using `bash` or `sed`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
$ cat 725364.in
[string one](/stringtwo/#stringthree)
[example label](/path/to/doc/#anchor)
$  sed 's_\(\[[^]]*]\)(/\([^#]*\)/\(#[^)]*\))_\1(\2.html\3)_g' 725364.in
[string one](stringtwo.html#stringthree)
[example label](path/to/doc.html#anchor)
```

To break it down:

Firstly, I use `s_needle_pin_flags` for `sed` rather than `s/needle/pin/flags` so as not to have to escape literal `/`s.

`sed` will search for, using this expression `\(\[[^]]*]\)(/\([^#]*\)/\(#[^)]*\))`, broken down as:

- `\(\[[^]]*]\)` - Definition of group 1 (the link label):

  - A literal `[`
  - Followed by zero or more or of anything that is not a `]`
  - Followed by a literal `]`
- `(/` - A literal `(/`
- `\([^#]*\)` - Definition of group 2 (the URL):

  - Zero or more of anything that is not a literal `#`
- `/` - A literal `/`
- `\(#[^)]*\)` - Definition of group 3 (the anchor):

  - A literal `#`
  - Followed by zero or more of anything that is not a literal `)`
- `)` - A literal `)`

And transform it using `\1(\2.html\3)`, broken down as:

- The match for group 1, followed by
- `(`, followed by
- The match for group 2, followed by
- `.html`, followed by
- The match for group 3, followed by
- `)`

Answer (score 3):

The group `\1` matched in `'s/](\(\/.*\)#/](\1.html#/g'` does really contain the slashes. You should specify the `\/` outside the group `\(\/.*\)`.
Try this:

```
sed -i 's/](\/\(.*\)\/#/](\1.html#/g' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -pe 's{ \( ~ \) [(\/) ( .+? ) (\/) (\# .+ )] $ } = "($1.html$3)";'  725364.in
```

#OR (more formally)

```perl
~$ raku -pe 's{ \( ~ \) [(\/) ( <-[#]>+? ) (\/) (\# <-[#]>+ )] $ } = "($1.html$3)";'  725364.in
```

Sample Input (thanks to @DopeGhoti):

```
[string one](/stringtwo/#stringthree)
[example label](/path/to/doc/#anchor)
```

Sample Output:

```
[string one](stringtwo.html#stringthree)
[example label](path/to/doc.html#anchor)
```

Because the OP wants to change `/` forward-slashes, a different syntax than the regular `s///` Raku substitution syntax is used. Raku also offers a `s{ … } = " … "` substitution syntax, which is used above (or `s[ … ] = " … "`, etc.).

In the first atom Raku's `~` tilde syntax for nested data structures is used. Basically the regex `\( ~ \) [ … ]` says *"the group in the square brackets is surrounded by parentheses"*. Then the regex goes on to capture a `/` forward slash into `$0`, a non-greedy sequence of characters into `$1`, a second`/` forward slash into `$2`, and a terminal greedy sequence of characters initiated by a `#` octothorpe into `$3`.

Display of captures (change `-pe` flags to `-ne` and add `say`):

```perl
~$ perl6 -ne 'say s{ \( ~ \) [(\/) ( .+? ) (\/) (\# .+ )] $ } = "($1.html$3)";'  725364.in
｢(/stringtwo/#stringthree)｣
 0 => ｢/｣
 1 => ｢stringtwo｣
 2 => ｢/｣
 3 => ｢#stringthree｣
｢(/path/to/doc/#anchor)｣
 0 => ｢/｣
 1 => ｢path/to/doc｣
 2 => ｢/｣
 3 => ｢#anchor｣
```

In the replacement, non-captured parentheses are restored. The captured `/` forward-slashes are dropped. The captured path in `$1` is output, followed by `.html` then followed by `$3` which is the captured `#` octothorpe-initiated, terminal string.

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org